# HttpModules Setting Being Ignored?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-config, httpmodule

I am upgrading an old WebForms application. However, it's not picking up the custom themes.

My web.config file contains the following:

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ThemeManager" type="SoftCircuits.MediCorp.ThemeManager"/>
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

And here's part of the definition of the class:

```
public class ThemeManager : IHttpModule
{
    const string _defaultTheme = "BlueSky";

    public ThemeManager()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication app)
    {
        app.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(Context_PreRequestHandlerExecute);
    }

    void Context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler is Page && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
            Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;

            // Note: To override the theme set here, set Theme = null in page's PreInit event
            if (page != null && !HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath.Contains("Help/"))
            {
            ...
```

But it appears that the class is never instantiated. I can set breakpoints in the constructor, the `Init()` handler, or the `PreRequestHandlerExecute()` handler, and none of those breakpoints are hit.

This worked at one time. Can anyone see what is missing?

*Note: I don't know if it makes any difference but I also specify `<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />` in my web.config file.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the web.config syntax has changed for IIS 7.0 Integrated mode (whatever Integrated mode means).

Instead of the configuration in my question, it needs to be done as follows.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="ThemeManager" type="SoftCircuits.MediCorp.ThemeManager"/>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

That fixed it for me.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227673(v=vs.100).aspx